# how add tag to pandas dataframe.to_html links so that absolute path of url will not shown in the html but a tag instead?

Tags: python, django, pandas

In my DataFrame I have column named `id` in it, I want to make this column clickable so that the HTML line in the table will be `<td><a href="../../link/to/{id}" target="_blank">{id}</a></td>`, the workaround I made is just replace to unicode that return from the `to_html` method:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
dict_df_example = {
    'ship_price': {0: 25.0, 1: 25.0},
    'name': {0: u'prodct example', 1: u'prodct example 2'},
    'when_seen': {0: Timestamp('2019-09-07 02:31:07'),
    1: Timestamp('2019-09-07 02:40:46')},
    'price': {0: 17.0, 1: 17.0},
    'id': {0: 101025072, 1: 101021537}
}
df_products = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_df_example)

list_ids = df_products.id.tolist()
df_products = df_products.to_html(index=False, table_id="table-id", render_links=True)
for id in list_ids:
    df_products = df_products.replace(
        '<td>{0}</td>'.format(id),
        '''<td><a href="../../link/to/{id}" target="_blank">{id}</a></td>'''.format(id=id)
    )
```

and then render this to HTML, in my HTML django template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ df_products }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

How can I achieve this functionality of get URL with label in pandas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found it , using apply function to create href without td like this :

```
df_products['id'] = df_products['id'].apply(create_clickable_id)
def create_clickable_id(id):
    url_template= '''<a href="../../link/to/{id}" target="_blank">{id}</a>'''.format(id=id)
    return url_template
```

and the most important is to add `escape=False` to pandas to_html method

```
df_products = df_products.to_html(index=False, table_id="sellers_table-id", render_links=True,escape=False)
```